# Get content by crawler from Angular app nested in MVC C# app

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework2, web-crawler

**UPDATE**:
Task is resolved by sending requests, still by cURL, using AJAX URLs used by Angular to communicate with .NET. URLs are to find using Inspect in browser.

So now I have:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/API_method/parameters");
```

**END UPDATE**

I need to get content using cURL library in crawler app based on Zend 2.0 PHP.

The content is inside Angular page. Angular app is nested in MVC C# .NET app working on IIS server.

I have it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
```

I'm getting response only from C# where is no page, so there is 404 error:

```
array(2) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(27) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(105) "http://www.example.com/"
    ["content_type"]=>
    string(29) "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
    ["http_code"]=>
    int(404)
...
```

How can I get content of Angular page?

Comment: If you can please add minimal code to your question that shows what you were trying, and an answer that shows the code you used to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, please see an update

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium WebDriver or [Chrome Headless](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php) because Angular works based on AJAX principles -- load data from API by browser with JavaScript

You can use practical wrappers, e.g. Codeception Test Framework